# NSSplitViewController does not call delegate methods

Tags: swift, macos, nssplitviewcontroller

I'm using an NSSplitViewController subclass and the delegate methods are not being called.

This is purely programmatically without nib/storyboard.

The code can be copied to a new project. The file needs to be named main.swift. Also remove "Main interface" in the project settings.

```
// File: main.swift

import Cocoa

// AppDelegate

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  let window = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 400),
    styleMask: [ .titled, .closable, .resizable ],
    backing: .buffered,
    defer: false
  )

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let splitViewController = MySplitViewController()
    window.contentView = splitViewController.view
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
  }

}

// NSSplitViewController

class MySplitViewController: NSSplitViewController {

  convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    // Left
    let viewController1 = NSViewController()
    viewController1.view = NSView()
    let item1 = NSSplitViewItem(viewController: viewController1)
    item1.minimumThickness = 100
    item1.maximumThickness = 200
    addSplitViewItem(item1)
    // Right
    let viewController2 = NSViewController()
    viewController2.view = NSView()
    let item2 = NSSplitViewItem(viewController: viewController2)
    addSplitViewItem(item2)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(splitView.delegate!)   // Logs "Project1.MySplitViewController"
  }

  // Never called
  override func splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, additionalEffectiveRectOfDividerAt dividerIndex: Int) -> NSRect {
    print("\(#function)")
    return super.splitView(splitView, additionalEffectiveRectOfDividerAt: dividerIndex)
  }

}

let application = NSApplication.shared
let applicationDelegate = AppDelegate()

application.delegate = applicationDelegate
application.run()
```

When running the code you can see that the split view shows up and works fine.

The viewDidLoad() method prints "Project1.MySplitViewController", so the delegate is set.

But the splitView(_:additionalEffectiveRectOfDividerAt:) method is not called (or any other NSSplitViewDelegate if implemented).

Comment: What are you doing to invoke that method?

Comment: This method is a delegate method, so it is not to be invoked by my code.

Comment: I understand. So when do you expect that this method is called? User interaction?

Comment: Why does this matter? Not one of the NSSplitViewDelegate methods is called.

Comment: Your sample doesn't work for me. "This is purely programmatically without nib/storyboard. The code can be copied to a new project" > "-[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: View in bundle (null)."

Comment: Same here. @Elliot: please provide a [example].

Comment: I changed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate method is not called because the `MySplitViewController` is released at the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Let `AppDelegate` hold a strong reference to the `MySplitViewController`.